# handling exception in function with return value

Tags: python, exception

If I have a function something like:

```
def foo(.. ):
  try:
    #something
    return_value = "bleh"
   except Exception,e:
     logging.error("exception " +e)
   return return_value
```

Does the above look ok? I mean, if I got the exception then `return_value` is never initialized.

What's a good way to handle exceptions in a function that has some return value?

Comment: You could consider returning `None`, but that may have unintended consequences on the calling function.

Comment: What would raise do in except part?

Comment: @Fraz yup, you can reraise the exception after logging it by using plain `raise`.

Comment: @alecxe: Yeah i think thats a better way than to return None?? though I guess it depends on use case.. Thanks

Comment: If choosing a suitable 'bad' return value is problematic, why not just re-raise the exception after logging it? Or raise another specific exception (e.g. define and then raise SomethingError())?

Comment: Also, you can use `logging.exception("Something failed")` which will log both the message "something failed" and the current exception traceback.

Comment: It all depends on what the function is intended to do. Suppose I want to read a config file but return a default if its not there or is corrupted. I would suppress the specific exceptions and return the default. An error in a function is not necessarily and error for the caller. It all depends on the design of that function.

Answer (score 2):

You should return a False or something of that kind to tell the caller that some error has occurred. And then handle this return value in your caller, like if return is False do something else.

```
def foo(.. ):
    try:
        #something
        return_value = "bleh"
     except Exception,e:
        logging.error("exception " +e)
        return_value = False
     return return_value
```